# aws: ec2 instance: unable to mount s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, mount

i have a ec2 instance with access to s3 bucket. But now i am not able to mount the s3 bucket into the ec2 instance

XXXXXXXXXXX  is the bucket name

```
sudo su
amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
yum install s3fs-fuse awscli python3 rsync -y
mkdir /s3_mount
echo "s3fs#XXXXXXXXXXX /s3_mount fuse _netdev,allow_other,iam_role=auto 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
mount -a --verbose
ls -al /s3_mount
```

```
[root@ip-172-31-29-95]# cat /etc/fstab
#
UUID=deb9f460-418e-4193-bc14-c9dc9c7b146e     /           ext4    defaults,noatime  1   1
s3fs#sant-test-s3-mount /s3_mount fuse _netdev,allow_other,iam_role=auto 0 0

[root@ip-172-31-29-95]# mount -a --verbose
/                        : ignored
/s3_mount                : successfully mounted

[root@ip-172-31-24-155 ec2-user]# ls -al /s3_mount/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 21 07:27 .
dr-xr-xr-x 20 root root 4096 Jul 21 07:27 ..
```

I dont see anything inside the s3_mount

whats wrong i am not sure

I want to try the above code as UserData for starting an EC2 instance. I tried the script

```
Resources:
  MyNewEC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-0fcbc9ed97efe271e
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      SubnetId: subnet-fc2df495
      KeyName: sant-test
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref Ec2InstanceProfile
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: |-
          #!/bin/bash
          set -x -o verbose;
          id
          amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
          yum install s3fs-fuse awscli python3 rsync -y
          mkdir /s3_mount
          echo "s3fs#XXXXXXXXX /s3_mount fuse _netdev,allow_other,iam_role=auto 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
          mount -a --verbose
          ls -al /s3_mount

  Ec2InstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
        - ecs-yyyyyyyy
```

I checked the logs `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` showing partial output

```
Complete!
mkdir /s3_mount
+ mkdir /s3_mount
echo "s3fs#sant-test-s3-mount /s3_mount fuse _netdev,allow_other,iam_role=auto 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
+ echo 's3fs#XXXXXXXXXXX /s3_mount fuse _netdev,allow_other,iam_role=auto 0 0'
mount -a --verbose
+ mount -a --verbose
/                        : ignored
/s3_mount                : successfully mounted
ls -al /s3_mount
+ ls -al /s3_mount
ls: cannot access /s3_mount: Software caused connection abort
```

it says `ls: cannot access /s3_mount: Software caused connection abort` Not sure why its says this. when i standalone try it only shows empty contents but does not throw error

Can someone guide how to do the mounting correctly

Comment: Is your bucket public?

Comment: I am able to mount using another s3fs mount